# Python sub-package references

Tags: python, import, package

I am about at wits end with what should be an extremely simple issue. Here is the format of a simple example that I wrote to try to fix my problem. I have a folder top with `__all__ = ["p1","p2"]` in `__init__.py` . I then have sub-folders p1 and p2 with `__init__.py` in both of them with `__all__` again defined with the names of two simple module quick1 and quick 2 with quick1 in p1 and quick2 in p2. If I import top.p1.quick1 from a script outside of top then the import works fine. However, trying to import top.p1.quick1 from quick2 gives the error 
`File "quick1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import top.p2.quick2
ImportError: No module named top.p2.quick2`

How can I import a module from another sub-package? This is supposed to work according to the python documentation as far as I can tell. Does anyone see an obvious, trivial mistake that I made?

Edit: It appears that I need to add the directory with top to my search path. I can do this temporarily by setting PYTHONPATH. However, is there a better way to do this from a distutils script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you describe is just fine and does not reproduce the error -- here's the simplest version I can think of:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/path
$ mkdir /tmp/path/top /tmp/path/top/p1 /tmp/path/top/p2
$ touch /tmp/path/top/__init__.py /tmp/path/top/p1/__init__.py /tmp/path/top/p2/__init__.py
$ touch /tmp/path/top/p1/quick1.py /tmp/path/top/p2/quick2.py$ echo 'import top.p1.quick1' > /tmp/path/top/p2/quick2.py
$ PYTHONPATH=/tmp/path python /tmp/path/top/p2/quick2.py
$ python -c 'import sys; sys.path.append("/tmp/path"); import top.p2.quick2'
```

and it runs just fine.  The `__all__` are not relevant unless you're using `from ... import *` which you aren't (and right you are not to).  As long as the parent directory of `top` (here, `/tmp/path`) is on `sys.path`, things will be fine; if that parent directory is not there, you'll get an error.

So what's the minimal change you can make to this sequence of operations to reproduce the error you observe?

Comment: I think his minimal change would be to change the last line to:
`echo 'import top.p2.quick2' > /tmp/path/top/p1/quick1.py; python /tmp/path/top/p1/quick1.py`

Comment: That would be one possible bug, yes -- one simple way of breaking the "As long as the parent directory of top (here, /tmp/path) is on sys.path" condition (to quote my answer -- ddaa's answer mentions it too). There are other bugs that could break that condition, though (putting `/tmp/path/top` in lieu of `/tmp/path` in `sys.path` is one bug frequently observed in the wild, for example -- a parent vs child confusion).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your top package is not in your sys.path.

Comment: Ah.That does seem to be the issue. I can temporarily add the directory to PYTHONPATH, but is there a way to add a directory permanently from distutils? Is there some other preferred way of adding the path?